# Once an AlternateView is created on a MailMessage, how can the content be modified?

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.mail

Once an `AlternateView` is created on a `MailMessage`, how can the content be modified?

In my mail generation process, I am first creating the `MailMessage` and an HTML `AlternateView`, and then I perform a series of transformations on the `MailMessage`.

Those transformations need to be able to update the HTML in the `AlternateView`, as well affect the `LinkedResources` attached to the `AlternateView`.

```
    MailMessage _email;

    public void PrepareEmail(string subject, string htmlBody)
    {
        // Create the Email 
        _email = new MailMessage();

        // Set the Subject
        _email.Subject = subject;
        _email.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        // Set the HTML Body
        _email.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; // needed?
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            htmlBody,
            null,
            MediaTypeNames.Text.Html
            );
        _email.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

    }

    public void TransformEmail()
    {
        // Perform a runtime-defined series of transformations,
        // which can modify any part of the Email, AlternateView, or LinkedResources. 
        // Primarily, I am modifying HTML, and adding LinkedResources. 
    }
```

I can retrieve AlternateView content as text using;

```
    public string GetAlternateViewText(AlternateView av)
    {
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert the Stream to a MemoryStream,
            // so that we can use ToArray()
            CopyStream(
                av.ContentStream,
                s
                );

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                s.ToArray()
                );
        }
    }

    public void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

However there doesn't appear to be any way to update the `AlternateView`'s content.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Arjang  "Once an AlternateView is created on a MailMessage, how can the content be modified?"

Comment: Try to remove the old one, create a new one with the new content and add it to the email.

Comment: Thanks @Arjang that's a much clearer question description.  I got too focused on the content and didn't notice it was incomplete.

Comment: @Gusman I'm hoping there's an easier and more direct solution. In a given situation I might have 200 transforms, so even if each one retrieves and sets the HTML only once, it's a fair number of destroy/create operations.  Also the `AlternateViewCollection` isn't keyed, which means creating a second collection to track which `AlternateView` object I want to rebuild.

Comment: May be then a better way of doing this is to first make all the transforms just to strings stored in a dictionary and once all transforms are applied then construct the alternate views.

Comment: @Gusman Yes, every `AlternateView`, and every `LinkedResource` as well.  That would still work for my purposes- an `EmailBuilder` class which tracks every piece of content through the composition process, transforms it all, and then generates the `Email`, `AlternateView`'s, `LinkedResource`'s, `Attachment`'s and so on.  But that seems like such an unnecessary amount of work to just update a little chunk of HTML.

Comment: Have you tried to use the ContentStream? I mean, get the stream, read it, modify, set the length of the stream to 0 and write the content again to it.

Comment: I hadn't considered that the underlying stream is most likely a MemoryStream.  Instead I went with the `MailBuilder` approach.  In my situation that extra investment makes sense, because there are quite a few options I need to control in the email construction process.  This way, the Transformers can simply be collected and attached, and then run whenever the raw HTML source updates.  Thanks for the tip- I intend to look into that more later.